# Is there any way to setup a device owner of a System Application?

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

I'm trying to setup a device owner of a system application. I tried `ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_DEVICE` intent but did not succeed. I know there are methods for setting up device owners with NFC and managed Google accounts but is there any way to set it up in a system application where I can use hidden APIs as well?